# Trouble reading file in xcode command line app

Tags: swift, xcode

I am having trouble reading a file within a command line tool project in Xcode 11.6.

Steps:

Create a new command line tool project using the template in the mac os section.

In main.swift:

```
import Foundation
let fileURL = URL( fileURLWithPath: "/Users/ausom4/Desktop/myTest.txt" )
var rawDataString: String
var errorString: String?

do {
  rawDataString = try String( contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8 )
  print(rawDataString)
} catch let error as NSError {
  errorString = error.description
  rawDataString = ""
  print(rawDataString)
}
```

This will build successfully in Xcode however will always print a null string in the console.

However if I go to the location of my product in terminal and run the build I get the contents of the file.

I do not have sandboxing enabled. Sandboxing is also not enabled by default in this xcode template. I have also given xcode full disk access.

I can run this code in a playground.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: The first step to debug the problem would be to `print(error)` ...

Comment: I get the following error:

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “myTest.txt” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/ausom4/Desktop/myTest.txt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1005425e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

I tried giving my file chmod 777 permissions, but the same error is returned

Answer (score 1):

It is not sandbox - it is macOS Security & Privacy system.

On first launch you had to get alert asking something like `“TestFileReading” would like to access files in your Desktop folder.` so you grand access for this application.

If you did not grant access then (or for some reason macOS `forgot` to ask that) there is possibility to grant access manually in System Preferences at any time:

[image: demo]

With all this passed your code snippet works as expected - tested with Xcode 12 / macOS 10.15.6

Comment: Unfortunately I never get a prompt from xcode when running the project for permissions to the desktop. I cannot add new apps to the flles and folders menu only remove them after unlocking. I am using 11.0 beta.